# Узнать есть ли запись в таблице и затем обновить или вставить

Tags: mysql, innodb

Есть некоторая таблица статистики. Пишется она за день по каждому юзеру, игре и т.д.
У меня есть уникальный индекс `hash_id`. Я просто строю хэш для нужных значений, затем проверяю, если есть запись с таким `hash_id`. И если она есть, то надо обновить, иначе вставить.
Таблица *InnoDB*.

Вчера похоже произошла ситуация, когда сделав `SELECT`, записи не нашлось, но параллельно запись вставилась другим процессом, и получили Integrity constraint violation...

Хотел было сразу `LOCK TABLES`, но пишут, что для таблиц *InnoDB* это неправильно.
Как правильно блокировать в этом случае таблицу?

P.s. конструкцию `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` не предлагать, т.к. *mysql* не умеет его реплицировать.

Comment: *хэш для нужных значений* — если под «значениями» подразумеваются столбцы, то лучше создать по ним составной уникальный индекс — пусть субд занимается той работой, под которую она и «заточена».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, были некоторые обстоятельства, которые вынудили сделать хэш вручную.  
Проблему составной индекс не решит.

Comment: Может быть Вам тогда использовать конструкцию [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

Comment: @ApInvent, я тоже слеповат - несколько вопросов с ru.so привел на эту конструкцию, а потом увидел, что его просят не предлагать

Answer (score 1):

Раз более подходящих вариантов не нашлось, пришлось использовать `LOCK TABLES`.
В принципе таблица блокируется совсем ненадолго.